# UIView width/height within UIStackView using Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I am trying to get a UICollectionView to remain a square (as large as possible) regardless of which orientation or iOS device.  I am using a UIStackView with two views vertically managed.  The top view is the one with the UICollectionView in it and is GameView.  GameView is set up to hug the top, both sides, and the second view (which is set up to be exactly 150 in height always).  This is the code I currently have:

```
if UIScreen.main.applicationFrame.size.width > UIScreen.main.applicationFrame.size.height {
        
        theCollection.frame.size.width = GameView.frame.size.height - 46
        theCollection.frame.size.height = GameView.frame.size.height - 46
        
        theCollection.frame.origin.y = 23
        theCollection.frame.origin.x = 23
        
        
    } else {
        
        theCollection.frame.size.width = GameView.frame.size.width - 46
        theCollection.frame.size.height = GameView.frame.size.width - 46
        
        theCollection.frame.origin.y = 23
        theCollection.frame.origin.x = 23
        
    }
```

However, this is resulting in a UICollectionView that is much smaller than it should be.  When I go in a take a look at the size of everything once it's built, the debugger prints out that GameView is only 414 wide, even though the screen is 768 wide (and I've put a color background on GameView and it shows that it is hugging all the sides as it should in the simulator).

Why is my GameView programmatically less wide than it is visually on the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to be setting frames to explicit values... use constraints and let auto-layout do all the work for you.

Second, if you want your collectionView to be **Square**, it will end up pretty small when the view's height is short -- such as a phone rotated to landscape orientation:

[image]

[image]

Here's example code to get that layout:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let stack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 0
        return v
    }()
    
    let gameContainerView = UIView()
    let secondView = UIView()
    
    var theCollection: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4
        theCollection = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        theCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        stack.addArrangedSubview(gameContainerView)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(secondView)
        
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(stack)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stack view to fill safe area
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            // second view always has a height of 150
            secondView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
        ])

        // add collection view to game container view
        gameContainerView.addSubview(theCollection)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // it looks like you want the collection view to be square (1:1 ratio)
            //  as large as possible
            //  with 23-pts on top/bottom or left/right, whichever is needed
            
            // give it a 1:1 ratio
            theCollection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theCollection.widthAnchor),
            
            // centered in container view
            theCollection.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameContainerView.centerXAnchor),
            theCollection.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameContainerView.centerYAnchor),
            
            // we need *at least* 23-pts "padding"
            theCollection.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: gameContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 23.0),
            theCollection.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: gameContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 23.0),
            theCollection.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: gameContainerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -23.0),
            theCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: gameContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -23.0),

        ])
        
        // we also need to constrain the collection view's
        //  Height and Width equal to the container's Height and Width
        //  but with Priority less than Required
        let w = theCollection.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameContainerView.widthAnchor)
        let h = theCollection.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gameContainerView.heightAnchor)
        w.priority = .defaultHigh
        h.priority = .defaultHigh
        w.isActive = true
        h.isActive = true

        // set background colors so we can easily see the frames
        theCollection.backgroundColor = .cyan
        gameContainerView.backgroundColor = .green
        secondView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        theCollection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        theCollection.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 42
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So, I've tried the method you list here and I have found it doesn't always work.  And it wouldn't work in this case because for some reason the View inside the Stack is ending up not as wide as the Stack even though I'm putting in constraints to make it always so.  My problem here is not that the making the box a square the right size doesn't work, it's that the View inside the Stack is causing it to be not correct because it's not out to the edges of the Stack.

Comment: @user14337541 - I don't understand... When you run this example code, do you get your desired result? If not, you'll need to explain in more detail what the problem is (some screen-caps of what you're getting compared to your desired result would help).